# KeyValuePair not working with JsonFx Serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Unable to serialize object KeyValuePair .
For example :

```
int[] test = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> test_d = new List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>();
test_d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("temp", 12));
test_d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("temp2", test));
Console.WriteLine(JsonFx.JsonWriter.Serialize(test_d));
```

Return `[{},{}]`
How do I fix this unfortunate situation? use similar within the meaning of "tuples" the result did not give.

Comment: Can you use Newtonsoft.Json instead JsonFX?

Comment: JsonFx is a 6 years old project which has not been supported for more than 4 years. I would use M. Wiśnicki code and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You sample is not compilebar. Try this out:

```
var writer = new JsonWriter();
Console.WriteLine( writer.Write(test_d));
```

I have output:

> {"temp":12,"temp2":[0,1,2,3,4,5]}

Answer (score 1):

I know answer is about JsonFX ,but You can also use Json.NET and serialize it like:

```
int[] test = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> test_d = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
test_d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("temp", 12));
test_d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("temp2", test));


 var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test_d, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
      TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
 });
```

Result will be:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "temp",
    "Value": 12
  },
  {
    "Key": "temp2",
    "Value": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  }
]
```